# Does Bootstrap break Fancybox 2 with Youtube?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, youtube, fancybox-2

After several hours trying to diagnose a problem, I figured out it is bootstrap.js that is causing fancybox / youtube to not work.  Anyone else experienced this, is it a known issue?

With bootstrap.js
http://wendymaggin.origindev.com/NashvilleCares/film_test.html

Without bootstrap.js
http://wendymaggin.origindev.com/NashvilleCares/film_test2.html

Is there any easy way to figure out where the offending line is in bootstrap.js to see if it can be eliminated without breaking a thousand other things?  Or, alternatively, is there an easy modification I can make to fancybox to fix this?  Not even sure where to start to try to figure out what is causing the actual issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6862 or https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/519 ... and eventually upgrade to bootstrap v2.3.1 (if you haven't) as suggested [here](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/6862#issuecomment-14899994)

Comment: ... just notice that the `.min` version may not work.